# <input type='file'> working only once when put inside iFrame (android and ios)

Tags: javascript, android, html, iframe, next.js

I am working on a `NextJs` project when I needed to implement a file picker. This whole project is embedded inside an `iFrame` to use for an android and ios projects.

The problem occurs in `android` and `ios` (works on the web).

The problem is when the user click the button to pick a file and then cancel without picking a file, then click the selection button again it doesn't work (the button onChange doesn't get fired).

Here is my code

```
                                <input
                                    type="file"
                                    style={{ display: "none" }}
                                    onChange={(event) => {
                                        handleInputImages(event.currentTarget.files);
                                        event.target.value = null;
                                        event.currentTarget.value = null;
                                    }}
                                    accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
                                    ref={imgInput}
                                />
                                <Button
                                    variant="primary"
                                    size="lg"
                                    onClick={() => imgInput.current.click()}
                                >
                                    Parcourir
                                </Button>

    

  const handleInputImages = (files) => {
    if (files) {
        for (const file of files) {
            const pattern = /image-*/;
            const reader = new FileReader();
            if (!file.type.match(pattern)) {
                alert("invalid format");
                return;
            }

            const fileSizeKiloBytes = file.size / 1024;
            if (fileSizeKiloBytes > MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
                setFileError(true)
                return;
            }

            reader.onload = async (e) => {
                let reader = e.target;
                var newImage = (reader.result as any).replace(
                    /^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/,
                    ""
                );
                setSelectedImage(newImage);
                setFileError(false)
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
    imgInput.current.value = null;
};
```

I've tried to set some values to null but that didn't work.

I put an alert inside the `handleInputImages` and it got fired only the first time, so I think the `onChange` get only fired once.

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm missing here ?

Comment: `event.target.value = null; event.currentTarget.value = null;` So you are clearing it? And you selecting the same file the second time?

Comment: Yes I'm clearing it because I had 2 problems, first which was solved is when I chose the same file twice, the second (this question) isn't solved.

Comment: If they select the same file there is no change. Maybe you wanted to use the blur event and not change.